# TypeError: Cannot read property 'app' of undefined when overwriting res.render

Tags: javascript, express

In my project I want to overwrite the `res.render` method to always add an option, no matter what other options there are. When I try to do it I get the error mentioned above. Here's my current middleware code:

```js
app.use((_, res, next) => {
    const oldRender = res.render;

    res.render = (view, options, callback) => {
        if (typeof options === "function") {
            callback = options;
            options = {};
        }

        options.stops = stops?.data || {};

        oldRender.call(this, view, options, callback);
    };

    next();
});
```

Comment: If you're trying to just make sure there's always a particular property available to your template, why not just assign it to `res.locals.stops = ...`.  That's what `res.locals` is for.

Comment: I suspect that your code isn't working because `this` is the wrong value.  You're using arrow functions  so `this` will be the lexical `this`, not the `this` that was originally passed to your method (e.g. not `res` which is what you need it to be).  But, as I said in my previous comment, I think this is the hard way to solve the original problem.

Comment: @jfriend00 the `this` thing fixed it. I changed the arrow function to a function. As for `res.locals` could you link an article so I can read about it?

Comment: Reference link for `res.locals` is in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the point of this code is to always pass a particular value to your templates without requiring every caller of `res.render()` to add that to the data they pass to the template.

The general-purpose way to solve this type of problem is to put a property in `res.locals`.  The template system looks there in addition to the data passed to `res.render()` and this is the easy way to pass data to all your templates:

```
app.use((_, res, next) => {
    res.locals.stops = stops?.data || {};
    next();
});
```

If there's some reason that won't work for you, then the apparent problem to the solution you're trying is that you're using `arrow` function so the value of `this` you're using in `oldRender.call(this, view, options, callback);` is the lexical value of `this`, not `res` which is what you need it to be.  You can change this:

```
oldRender.call(this, view, options, callback);
```

to this:

```
return oldRender.call(res, view, options, callback);
```

You can directly pass `res` instead of trying to use `this` and you should also return the return value (which will be `res`) to duplicate the original behavior.

---

Doc [link](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.locals) on `res.locals`.

A few other answers about `res.locals`:

[Difference between assigning to res and res.locals in node.js (Express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24072333/difference-between-assigning-to-res-and-res-locals-in-node-js-express)

[Is this bad practice for res.locals? (Node.js, express)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67511690/is-this-bad-practice-for-res-locals-node-js-express)